# Change Default Master Volume Control to "PCM" in alsamixer on Linux Mint

Tags: audio, linux-mint, gnome, alsa

I am running Linux Mint and whenever I use my system's hardware volume controls (e.g., volume up/down buttons), it adjusts the "PCM 1" level in alsamixer. However, I want it to adjust the "PCM" level instead.

Here's the output from `amixer -c 1` which shows the available controls:

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 74
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',1
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 74
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 74
  Mono: Capture 74 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

I have tried modifying PulseAudio's default.pa configuration, but this resulted in loss of audio.

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve custom scripts or keybindings. I'd prefer to have the standard master volume change "PCM" directly.

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

[image: alsamixer overview]